# Read-only access to GData API with OAuth

Tags: oauth, gdata-api, gdata

I'm using the [Google Documents List API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/) to get a list of documents and export their contents.  I'm authenticating with OAuth (3-legged). It's been very straightforward, with one exception. I'm not finding a way to request read-only access to documents. I'm using a [scope](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/faq.html#AuthScopes) of `https://docs.google.com/feeds/` when fetching the oauth request token.

Is there a way to request read-only access to Doc List API? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/#readonly
```

At least thats the schema used for 2-legged OAuth for Marketplace applications

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162106

I don't know if it will work in your case.